# Magento. How to get to a tab(which created by my module) in BO->System->configuration without logout and than login?

Tags: php, magento

Every time a created the mudule in which I set a new tab in BO->System->configuration, first I entered in BO(login), go to System->configuration to my tab(everything is good-I see my tab), but after click on it a have a page 404. Than I log out and log in , go to System->configuration to my tab, click on it, everything is good now, I got a page with a fields which I created by my module. Cleaning a cache do not help.
Always when I create a new module I have to log in and than log out and log in again to get into my module. Can I avoid this procedure??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, no. Magento store acl permissions in the session, so to update it you need to relogin. You can creare an extensión to update sesión by some trigger.